# are SSIS raw files the best way to exchange data between two SQL Server data warehouses?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

This is the context: An extract from one SQL server 2012 DWH will be consumed by another SQL Server 2012 DWH in a different network. Regardless the format, the feed will be transmitted via SFTP. I normally extract data in csv to feed external data marts but I wonder if raw file is a better option since both, extract from the source and load in destination, will be handled by SSIS packages.

Answer (score 1):

The raw file would be my choice, as it maintains each fields' metadata and is in a compact binary format.